# How to print a specific line from tkinter multiline Text widget

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, text, tkinter, widget

I have this text written in tkinter multiline TEXT widget.

He is a boy.

It will rain soon

Today is Sunday.

.

if i type row number for eg. 2
it should print 2nd line "It will rain soon"

how to find end of line ?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply modifiers to an index. So, for example, to get the end of line three you can use the index `"3.0 lineend"`. For example:

```
the_text.get("3.0", "3.0 lineend")
```

The definitive reference to indexes and their modifiers is in the tcl/tk documentation here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M7

Answer (score 0):

You could also save the entire text as a string and then split the string at each line break. Then simply select whichever line you need.

```
lines = 'He is a boy. \n It will rain soon \n Today is Sunday.'
line_list = lines.split('\n')
print line_list[0]
print line_list[1]
print line_list[2]

>>>>He is a boy.
>>>>It will rain soon
>>>>Today is Sunday.
```